# ElasticSearch find doc by phrase with/without extra words

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, elasticsearch-dsl

I use ***span_near*** with ***fuzzy query*** to search text by phrase. It works well if I type exact phrase even if words order is wrong. But I want to find NOT exact phrase, but something very similar.

For example:

**I have such text:**

> I wake up early because his dog barks loudly

**And these search cases, when my doc must be found:**

> I wake up early

(exact phrase)

> I wake up because dog barks

(missing some little word in the middle of phrase)

> I always wake up early because dog barks

(added some extra word in the middle)

**But in these cases doc shouldn't be found:**

> I wake up and bark

(too many missing words in phrase)

> I wake up often at the 2 am and when the Moon is alright wolves bark under my window.

(too many additinal words in phrase)

**I would be appreciate if someone helps me! This is the code I use (words seperated by space and each one added to a span_multi object):**

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "span_near": {
                        "clauses": [
                            {
                                "span_multi": {
                                    "match": {
                                        "fuzzy": {
                                            "text": {
                                                "value": "I",
                                                "fuzziness": 2
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "span_multi": {
                                    "match": {
                                        "fuzzy": {
                                            "text": {
                                                "value": "wake",
                                                "fuzziness": 2
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "span_multi": {
                                    "match": {
                                        "fuzzy": {
                                            "text": {
                                                "value": "up",
                                                "fuzziness": 2
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }   }
                            }
                        ],
                        "slop": 5,
                        "in_order": false
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "size": 20,
    "from": 0,
    "sort": [
        {
            "petition_number": {
                "unmapped_type": "keyword",
                "order": "asc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you give a more precise definition for "missing some little word", "too many missing words in phrase" and "too many additinal words in phrase". Which words are "little" and which words are "not little"? Is there a list of "little" words? Can "too many missing" and "too many additional" be expressed numerically? Is it 1, 2, 100?

Comment: @imotov It would be better, if I could set its count as a persent of words in phrase. For example, 20% of differences in phrase would be enough.

Comment: And what does phrase mean? Is it an entire field?

Comment: @imotov No. In the examples above you can see that phrase is the part of text in field. The text should fully contain this part OR there should be something very similar in meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Your query example works pretty well, except for "missing some little word in the middle of phrase" use case. Unfortunately, there is no `minimum_should_match` parameter in the `span_near` query, so you might need to generate all possible version of your query. Basically if you are searching for `I always wake up early` and you are ok with one word missing, you would generate the queries for phrases.

- `always wake up early`
- `I wake up early`
- `I always up early`
- `I always wake early`
- `I always wake up`

I know that this is not the solution that you are looking for, but I think that's the best solution possible with stock elasticsearch unless you are willing to change your requirements.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think, it is a possible way out. In fact, we can throw out the first and the last phrases, because phrase will match anyway, no matter how many words  there are before or after the phase in the sentense. 

So, there will be N-2 phrases joined with "OR" operator, where N is the number of words in the original search phrase. I have some doubts about perfomance with large amount of words, but I think, I can test it.

Thank you)